# Updating/Saving values of dynamic dropdown menu entirely populated by other dropdown menus in JS

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I would like to be able to make a series of dropdown menus that are, themselves, populated by dropdown menus. When a user updates one of the base selections, I want to change the secondary selections only if the selection that had been selected was changed. For example;

```
"Base menus" (all dropdown menus)

Menu 1 options: "red", "blue", "green"
Menu 2 options: "House", "Shed", "Complex"
Menu 3 options: "small", "tiny", "Huge", "normal"
Menu 4 options: "expensive", "cheap", "average"

"Secondary Menus"
Menu 5 options: "Result of Menu 1", "Result of Menu 2", Result of Menu 3", Result of Menu 4";
Menu 6 options (Same as menu 5)
Menu 7 options (same as menu 5)
```

Then I would like the user to select anything they want in menus 1-4, then select what they want in menus 5 through 7. Then, when they change a selection in any of the first 4 menus, that change dynamically populates through menus 5 through 7 as needed (both as new dropdown selection options and replacing the option if it was selected).

This seems like it should be easy enough, but I'm very new to html and js and I'm still learning how a lot of this code works (I programmed in other languages before, but this is different enough that the structure is still foreign to me). I can make the above work, but it's by brute forcing the html, and whenever a base option is "updated" it resets all the secondary menus to the default... so really I'd like to be able to set the secondary menus options to be "whatever you chose in menus 1-4" rather than hard coding it and running some script to repopulate the options every time one of the "base menus" is changed (which is how I am currently doing it).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm not even sure where to look, or what syntax/functions to lookup or Google to find useful information...

As an aside, I'm game to try CSS but really don't understand that code well at all; I have a reasonable grip on js and html so far, haven't really cracked CSS much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can dynamically populate/update your secondary menus with javascript/jQuery alone other than the way you are doing now.

But you will be able to achieve this using javascript frameworks like Angular, React, Vue where you have models/data/props which you can rely on for building the secondary menus. And as when a selection is updated in your primary menus you can update the model/data/props and it will automatically update the secondary menus.